# Why is my firestore paginate query not working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

basically im trying to achive pagination,,,but my paginate query returns same result each time i change **startAt** or **currentPage** why is that ?

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  let fetchedBlogs = []
  const startAt = currentPage * itemsPerPage - itemsPerPage
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  db.collection("blogs").where("userUid", "==", user.uid).orderBy("createdAt").startAt(startAt).limit(itemsPerPage).get().then(querySnapShot => {
    querySnapShot.forEach(doc => fetchedBlogs.push(doc.data()))
    return fetchedBlogs
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the same document because `startAt` is constant.
If you want to paginate documents, you must like code this:

```js
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad , i taught startAt takes an index value but it actually takes a field value,,
like for example

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
                  .orderBy("population")
                  .limit(25);

          return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
            // Get the last visible document
            var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
            console.log("last", lastVisible);

            // Construct a new query starting at this document,
            // get the next 25 cities.
            var next = db.collection("cities")
                    .orderBy("population")
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)
                    .limit(25);
          });
```